# Want to change subtitle tag style in video

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer

I have a SRT File, for subtitles am using `MPMoviePlayer`.

Finally, Got subtitle and showing successfully .

I add a tag `< I >First< /I > Text Example` but its not working. So how to change text style (Italic,Bold)

Comment: Can you link to the library you are using for showing subtitles?

Comment: https://github.com/mhergon/MPMoviePlayerController-Subtitles

Comment: The only way to do this is to have `NSAttributedString` instead of `NSString`, else you can't have various format on the same `UILabel`, thing that your library don't do. That's why it doesn't even parse the NSString for tags like italics. You have to customize the parsing and use NSAttributedString.